# allow a variable to be any struct which embeds another struct?

Tags: go, oop, inheritance, struct

I'm writing an app that needs to be able to choose between different message passing methods, like Kafka or RabbitMQ. When the app starts up, it will use some config variable to determine which type of message passing it needs to use, and instantiate it accordingly. To keep things as easy as possible, I'm trying to set up a `struct` with some common fields, and then embedding that into the individual `struct`s for my implementations.

However, if I do that, and then try to use the "child" `struct`s where I've declared something as the "parent," I get type errors.

Is there a way to do what I'm aiming for?

```golang
type Messenger struct {
  msgOut chan string
  errOut chan string
}

type KafkaMessenger struct {
  Messenger
  client *kafka.Client
}

type RabbitMessenger struct {
  Messenger
  client *rmq.Client
}

func NewKafkaMessenger(outChan chan string, errChan chan error) *KafkaMessenger {
 // create a new kafka messenger
}

func NewRabbitMessenger(outChan chan string, errChan chan error) *RabbitMessenger {
 // create a new rabbit messenger
}

type Env struct {
  Messenger
}

func main() {
  env := Env{}
  msgType := os.Getenv("MESSAGE_TYPE")
  
  // This block fails because neither method produces a strict 'Messenger' type
  if msgType == 'KAFKA' {
    env.Messenger = NewKafkaMessenger(...)
  } else {
    env.Messenger = NewRabbitMessenger(...)
  }
}
```

So my question is this - if I want to store the output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an interface:

```
type MessengerImpl struct {
  msgOut chan string
  errOut chan string
}

func (m MessengerImpl) Out() chan string {return m.msgOut}
func (m MessengerImpl) Err() chan string {return m.errOut}

type Messenger interface {
  Out() chan string
  Err() chan string
}

type KafkaMessenger struct {
  MessengerImpl
  client *kafka.Client
}

type Env struct {
  Messenger
}
```

When you embed the `MessengerImpl`, the embedding struct will implement the `Messenger` interface, and thus you can pass it to places that require a `Messenger`.

Comment: If I attempt to replicate your code, I get an error - `invalid receiver type Messenger (pointer or interface type)`

Comment: That should've been MessangerImpl. See the updated code.

Comment: Well, I thought I had it fixed, but I'm still seeing the problem. Here is a gist with the basics of what I'm doing: https://gist.github.com/kwhitaker/a8fab8707be4aa1f8119fc994d43b984

I'm sure I'm missing something easy

Comment: @KevinWhitaker there's no inheritance in Go. Embedding a type will not make the __embedder__ type interchangeable with the __embedded__ type. An embedded field is still JUST a field. Nothing else. Composition. If the `broker` parameter of `processOutgoingMessage` should accept arguments of different implementations (i.e. different types), then the broker parameter's type should be an __interface__ type _(not a struct type as you have now)_, and the set of all valid broker types that you would like to pass to `processOutgoingMessage` MUST implement that interface.

Comment: @KevinWhitaker you probably want something like: `func processOutgoingMessage(broker messaging.MessageBroker, msg messaging.OutgoingMessage) {` -- your `messaging.MessageBroker` is an __interface__, but `messaging.MessageBrokerImpl` is NOT. So if you specify `messaging.MessageBrokerImpl` (a struct type) as the parameter to the func then the argument passed to the call expression cannot be anything other than `messaging.MessageBrokerImpl`. But if you use `messaging.MessageBroker` (an interface) as the parameter type, then the argument can be ANYTHING that _implements_ `messaging.MessageBroker`.

Comment: Ah yeah - that seems to have fixed the issue. Thanks so much!